# Shopify Call a json file in JavaScript code from assets

Tags: javascript, json, shopify

Shopify...
I have uploaded a json file into assets. I have JavaScript code which requires the directories of the json file. Please see the  following code below-

```
container: elem,
        renderer: 'svg',
        loop: false,
        autoplay: true,
        rendererSettings: {
            progressiveLoad:false
        },
        path: 'data.json'   <-----I need to call the json file here   it is already uploaded into assests*******************************************************>
    };
    anim = bodymovin.loadAnimation(animData);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call this file path using below code

```
{{'data.json'| asset_url}}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out but i add the a json codes inside js. I will try your technique next time on my projects.

Comment: Actually, your solution seems to be more appropriate @Md.RezwanFerdous . Thanks for the idea

Comment: yeah but it's weird to see a long json string in a js variable..there more elegant solution i found after diving into js for the last two years.